# construct non-commutative group with prescribed center

Tags: group-theory

I want to construct an affine noncommutative group $G$ over a field of char zero with a prescribed center $Z(G)$. How do I do this?

Comment: Why not take the product with $PGL(2)$?

Comment: You don't, because not all abelian groups occur as the center of some algebraic group. In other words: You're missing some restrictions here for the question to be nontrivial.

Comment: What is an affine group? Do you mean an affine algebraic group?